# Android managing ListViewItem Progressbar update in row

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I'm using ListView with custom list rows,where every ListItem has ProgressBar in it.

When the user click the ImageView,the app starts an AsyncTask to download a file from a remote server,and update the progress in progress bar.

I'm using Parallel async tasks,which mean app can launch multiple downloads and update them in the ProgressBar of each row.

This is the code'

```
 static class ViewHolder {
protected TextView title;
protected TextView size;
protected TextView version;
protected ImageView appIcon;
protected ProgressBar progressBar;
}

public class UpdateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UpdateItem> {


public UpdateAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UpdateItem> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    UpdateItem updateItem = getItem(position);
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    if (convertView == null) { // if convertView is null
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.apptitlelabel);
        viewHolder.version = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.versionlabel);
        viewHolder.size = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sizelabel);
        viewHolder.appIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appicon);
        viewHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    viewHolder.progressBar.setProgress(0);

    View finalConvertView = convertView;
    viewHolder.appIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            DownloadFileFromURL task = new DownloadFileFromURL();
            task.position = position;
            task.v = finalConvertView;
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, updateItem.downloadlink);

        }
    });
 return convertView;
}



class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

/**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
 **/
int position;
View v;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

/**
 * Downloading file in background thread
 **/
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();

        // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
        // progress bar
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                8192);

        // Output stream
        String fileExtenstion = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url.getPath());
        String fname = URLUtil.guessFileName(url.getPath(), null, fileExtenstion);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + fname);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
 }

/**
 * Updating progress bar
 **/
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage

    // Log.w(TAG, progress[0]);
    updateStatus(position, Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 **/
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
    Log.w(TAG, "onPostExecute: ");

    removeListItem(v, position);
}
}


public void updateStatus(int index, int Status) {

int in = index - updateLv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = updateLv.getChildAt(in);

ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
progress.setProgress(Status);

}
```

The problem is ,when the user starts two downloads(say hit the first the second imageviews),and the first task has been completed,and the first row getting removed from the list,in onPostExecute,now,the second row turns into the first row,but the task updates the current second row(which was the third before the first item removed...)

I know it happens because I pass into `updateStatus`,the position of the item to be updated,but in the meantime the ListView Changes and removes items(because their download has been completed),but I have no current solution for this...

I even tried passing the `ProgressBar` object reference to updateStatus method ,instead of using item position,and I thought it would solve the problem...but no luck :)

I tried also to track the items positions with hashmap..with no success... :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is also in `removeListItem(v, position);`, first and third item will be removed in your example. To solve the problem, try providing each item with an unique ID, you can add a field in your **UpdateItem** class, here I demostrate with a seperate ArrayList.

1. Change adapter constructor, add an ArrayList and a private method:

   ```
    public UpdateAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UpdateItem> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
        resetIds(users.size());
    }

    ArrayList<String> arrayIds = new ArrayList<>();

    private void resetIds(int size) {
        arrayIds.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) arrayIds.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
   ```
2. Inside the OnClickListener, add `task.id = arrayIDs.get(position);` just before execute AsynTask.
3. In AsynTask, add a field `String id;`, change methods **onProgressUpdate** and **onPostExecute**.

   ```
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage

        // Log.w(TAG, progress[0]);
        //updateStatus(position, Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        updateStatus(id, Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        Log.w(TAG, "onPostExecute: ");

        removeListItem(v, position); // Problem, later fix it yourself
        arrayIds.remove(id);
    }
   ```
4. Change **updateStatus**

   ```
    public void updateStatus(String id, int Status) {

        int index = arrayIds.indexOf(id);
        int in = index - updateLv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = updateLv.getChildAt(in);

        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
        progress.setProgress(Status);

    }
   ```

Use ArrayList of Integer for **arrayIds** may be better but need to be careful when add the code `arrayIds.remove(id);` in **onPostExecute**, be sure selected `remove(object o)`, not `remove(int index)`. If this works, then use the same appoach to fix **removeListItem**.